# unreported exception when throwing from a lambda in a Completable Future

Tags: java, future, completable-future

When I compile the code below, I get the following error:

```
/home/prakashs/composite_indexes/src/main/java/com/spakai/composite/TwoKeyLookup.java:22: error: unreported exception NoMatchException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        CompletableFuture<Set<V>> result = calling.thenCombine(called, (s1, s2) -> findCommonMatch(s1, s2));
```

The code:

```
 public CompletableFuture<Set<V>> lookup(K callingNumber, K calledNumber) throws NoMatchException {
        CompletableFuture<Set<V>> calling = callingNumberIndex.exactMatch(callingNumber);
        CompletableFuture<Set<V>> called = calledNumberIndex.exactMatch(calledNumber);
        CompletableFuture<Set<V>> result = calling.thenCombine(called, (s1, s2) -> findCommonMatch(s1, s2));
        return result;
    }

    public Set<V> findCommonMatch(Set<V> s1, Set<V> s2) throws NoMatchException {
        Set<V> intersection = new HashSet<V>(s1);
        intersection.retainAll(s2);

        if (intersection.isEmpty()) {
          throw new NoMatchException("No match found");
        }

        return intersection;
    }
```

I am already declaring it to be thrown. What am I missing?

The full code is in https://github.com/spakai/composite_indexes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checked Exceptions are much older than Java promises and do not work well with them as of Java 8. Technically speaking, [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) does not declare throwing any checked Exception. As such, your `findCommonMatch`, which you pass to `thenCombine`, can not throw them either.

Make `NoMatchException` unchecked by inheriting from `RuntimeException`. Also remove the misleading `throws` declaration from the lookup method — it is not throwing anything — the code, being encapsulated within promise, is going to throw, not method creating promise.

Exceptions thrown within promises are by design completely invisible to code, that creates them and subscribes to them. Instead you are usually expected to use unchecked exceptions and handle them in a way, specific for particular promise library (see documentation of [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) for details on it's exception handling facilities).

Comment: Here is a solution that allows you to use checked exceptions without reducing the readability of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705336/14731