# Throwing checked exceptions with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

Stackoverflow contains multiple questions about mixing checked exceptions with `CompletableFuture`.

Here are a few examples:

- [Checked exception with CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39340239/14731)
- [Java 8 Supplier Exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28959849/14731)
- [JDK8 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync how to deal with interruptedException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23184964/14731)

While some of answers hint at the use of `CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally()` their approach results in user code that is difficult to read.

I will use this space to provide an alternate solution that results in improved readability.

**Please note that this question is specific to CompletableFuture.** This allows us to provide solutions that do not extend to lambda expressions more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `Completions` utility class (provided below) users can throw checked exceptions seamlessly:

```
public CompletionStage<String> readLine()
{
  return Completions.supplyAsync(() ->
  {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")))
    {
      return br.readLine();
    }
  });
}
```

Any exceptions thrown by the lambda (checked or not) will be wrapped in a `CompletionException`, which is consistent with `CompletableFuture`'s behavior for unchecked exceptions.

Things get a bit uglier for intermediate steps like `thenApply()` but it's not the end of the world:

```
public CompletionStage<String> transformLine()
{
  return readLine().thenApply(line ->
    Completions.wrapExceptions(() ->
    {
      if (line.contains("%"))
        throw new IOException("Lines may not contain '%': " + line);
      return "transformed: " + line;
    }));
}
```

Here some methods from the `Completions` utility class. You can wrap other `CompletableFuture` methods this way.

```
/**
 * Helper functions for {@code CompletionStage}.
 *
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class Completions
{
    /**
     * Returns a {@code CompletionStage} that is completed with the value or exception of the {@code CompletionStage}
     * returned by {@code callable} using the supplied {@code executor}. If {@code callable} throws an exception the
     * returned {@code CompletionStage} is completed with it.
     *
     * @param <T>      the type of value returned by {@code callable}
     * @param callable returns a value
     * @param executor the executor that will run {@code callable}
     * @return the value returned by {@code callable}
     */
    public static <T> CompletionStage<T> supplyAsync(Callable<T> callable, Executor executor)
    {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> wrapExceptions(callable), executor);
    }

    /**
     * Wraps or replaces exceptions thrown by an operation with {@code CompletionException}.
     * <p>
     * If the exception is designed to wrap other exceptions, such as {@code ExecutionException}, its underlying cause is wrapped; otherwise the
     * top-level exception is wrapped.
     *
     * @param <T>      the type of value returned by the callable
     * @param callable an operation that returns a value
     * @return the value returned by the callable
     * @throws CompletionException if the callable throws any exceptions
     */
    public static <T> T wrapExceptions(Callable<T> callable)
    {
        try
        {
            return callable.call();
        }
        catch (CompletionException e)
        {
            // Avoid wrapping
            throw e;
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e)
        {
            throw new CompletionException(e.getCause());
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            throw new CompletionException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@code CompletionStage} that is completed with the value or exception of the {@code CompletionStage}
     * returned by {@code callable} using the default executor. If {@code callable} throws an exception the returned
     * {@code CompletionStage} is completed with it.
     *
     * @param <T>      the type of value returned by the {@code callable}
     * @param callable returns a value
     * @return the value returned by {@code callable}
     */
    public static <T> CompletionStage<T> supplyAsync(Callable<T> callable)
    {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> wrapExceptions(callable));
    }

    /**
     * Prevent construction.
     */
    private Completions()
    {}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a great idea to be catching all `Throwable` types and wrapping in a `CompletionException`.  In particular, I would have thought this is particularly bad for `java.lang.Error`.

Comment: @msandiford If you dig into the `CompletableFuture` implementation you will see that they do the same (e.g. in the `uniApply()` method). Users want to be able to log errors like `AssertionError` otherwise their code just fails silently and they have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: maybe I'm missing the point you are trying to make, but doesn't the `CompletableFuture` machinery handle this case? In what situation is an `AssertionError` (for example) going to be swallowed without resulting in a user-visible `ExecutionException` somewhere in the pipeline?

Comment: @msandiford The reason that `CompletableFuture` machinery handles this case is because it catches `Throwable`. This wrapper has to provide the same functionality as the underlying implementation *plus* support checked exceptions. As a result, if the underlying implementation catchs `Throwable` then the wrapper have to as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. declare helper class

```
public class CompletableFutureHelper {

    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Callable<T> callable) {
        return supplyAsync(callable, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
    }

    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Callable<T> callable, Executor executor) {
        final CompletableFuture<T> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                completableFuture.complete(callable.call());
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                completableFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        });
        return completableFuture;
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<?> runAsync(RunnableExceptionable runnableException) {
        return runAsync(runnableException, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<?> runAsync(RunnableExceptionable runnableException, Executor executor) {
        return supplyAsync(() -> {
            runnableException.run();
            return null;
        }, executor);
    }

    public interface RunnableExceptionable {
        void run() throws Exception;
    }
}
```

2. use it like

```
        try {
            CompletableFutureHelper.runAsync(() -> Thread.sleep(1000)).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "readFileContent=" + Arrays.toString(CompletableFutureHelper.supplyAsync(() -> Files.readAllBytes(new File("/data/1.txt").toPath())).get()));
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```